# Using react-fine-uploader, how to get response from server for successfully uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
this.uploader.on('onAllComplete', (succeeded, failed) => {
  const successfulUploadResponses = succeeded.map(o => this.uploader.methods.something(o)));

  // do something w/successfulUploadResponses
});
```

I need to fill in the `something` above. Can I access the response for each uploaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onComplete` callback](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/5.16.2/client/typescript/fine-uploader.d.ts#L1967) is called when an item completes uploading.
It is passed `id`, `name`, `responseJSON` and `xhr` for the uploaded item.

The `responseJSON` for completed uploads can be stored in an object using file id as key.

In the `onAllComplete` callback, `responseJSON` can be retrieved using the file id in the array of successful uploads.

```
 const RESPONSE_JSON = {};

 this.uploader.on('onComplete', (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) => {
    RESPONSE_JSON[id] = responseJSON;
 })

 this.uploader.on('onAllComplete', (succeeded, failed) => {
  const successfulUploadResponses = succeeded.map(id => RESPONSE_JSON[id]);

  // do something w/successfulUploadResponses
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the event I was missing.